# VB6 Error when calling SQL Server SP: "Operation is not allowed when the object is closed"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, vb6, adodb

I have an old VB6 application that used to be connected to production sybase database. The database was recently migrated to SQL Server 2008 R2 and now I'm the process to update the app to keep it up-and-running. 
The error I'm getting is "**Operation is not allowed when the object is closed**".

This is the structure of the code on VB6:

```
Dim sql as String
Dim connString as String
Dim conn as New ADODB.Connection 

connString = "Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=CatalogName;Data Source=Production_Server_Name;"
sql = "EXEC sp_name @param1, @param2, @param3, @param4"

conn.Open connString

Dim Cmd as ADODB.Command
Set Cmd = New ADODB.Command 
Set Cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
Cmd.CommandText = sql
Cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
Cmd.CommandTimeOut = 300

Dim rs as ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open sql, conn --> The Code fails on this line !!!

Set rs = Cmd.Execute() 

If rs Is Nothing Or IsNull(rs) Then
  Set rs = Nothing
  bla bla bla 
  bla bla
End
```

The stored procedure code is as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_name 
(
    @param1 as integer, 
    @param2 as integer,
    @param3 as integer, 
    @param4 as nvarchar(150)
 )
 AS
  SET NOCOUNT ON

 -- All the code goes here

 RETURN
```

***Code Structure Notes***:

- @param1, @param2 and @param1 are integer defined values. @param4 is comma separated string value
- I already know ADODB objects can be declared and instanciated at the same line.

***Validations I already did/Suggestions already tried without success***:

- The SP works perfectly when executed from SSMS with a read-only
  database user.
- The SP DOES use variable tables (@VariableTables) for intermediate
  processing stuffs.
- The VB6 code WORKS when calling the "sp_who" bult-in SQL Server SP
- The VB6 code WORKS when sql variable contains "SELECT TOP 1 Column FROM
  DB.dbo.Table"
- The SP FAILS even when using full-qualification for the call (EXEC
  DB.dbo.sp_name)
- The SP FAILS even when removing the "EXEC" part of the sql variable

Any word to put light on this topic error be really appreciated and the correct answer accepted inmediately.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Based on what you have already tried, it seems there might be an issue in the SP code itself.

Comment: Try to comment out different sections of the SP, then when the SP runs, you know which section of the SP it has a problem with.

Comment: Also, you can run the SQL Profiler and turn on error catching so you can see what if any error is being created in the SP.

Comment: A couple of things: 1. Ensure you are using client side cursors, 2. Have you tried using a different provider (like sqloledb)

Comment: You're missing opening the connection before the execution of the command.

Comment: @Jeremy Thanks for your comments. SQL Profiler help me to discover there was execute permission issue on the SP I was calling caused by the DB migration process.

Comment: @G21 no problem. The Profiler is a VERY handy tool to keep around to see what your system is actually doing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to open the connect first.

```
Dim rs as ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

conn.Open()  <-- missing this

rs.Open sql, conn 

Set rs = Cmd.Execute()
```